# Can I get freelance QA (QA Lead or QA Manager) role through my sqa.stackexchange.com reputation?

Tags: qa-role, career-development

I would like to get a `freelance QA project or a role`, that could be done remotely.

Is that plausible role through my `sqa.stackexchange.com` reputation?

Any leads or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: This question looks openion-based. No one can say you if some 3rd person would value your reputation on sqa.stackexchange.

Comment: Yes, it's a tad subjective.

Comment: How are you going to pick the proper answer then?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you mean by "through" - obviously, this is not a job board. A quick check of [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=quality+assurance) shows that companies are hiring people for QA roles though the network, and they'd be quite silly to use Stack Overflow for hiring for a QA role without looking at the candidate's SQA profile.

Outside of that, I have used my Stack Exchange profile in the interview process multiple times to successful effect. Being able to point to situations where you absorbed someone's problem, applied your personal and professional experience to solving that problem, and received approval from the community at large does tend to be looked upon favorably by employers.

As a moderator I feel obliged to inform you that comments referring to a job search, like "I can help with that, email me at rohan@rohaninc.com for rates" will be promptly removed. (I don't want to be a jerk, it's just... that's not what we're about here!) I would highly recommend, however, putting in your profile that you're available for freelance work.

Answer (score 4):

If I were the person taking a decision on if a candidate fits the requirements for a certain QA position and I had their SQA profile **I would certainly examine that but not for the reputation**. Because there is a lot of ways actually how one can gain reputation here. Some of them, personally I, consider valuable for my hypothetical employees and some not.

I would rather examine the profile for the following:

- If a person asks a question

  - how concrete the question is
  - how well the persons worked on their own before asking
  - if a person understands what their ask and why.
  - If there is an example in the question how relevant and optimal it is
- If a person answers the question

  - How well it covers the issue stated by the OP
  - If the answer looks optimal (does not provide information that is hardly relevant to the question)
  - How interesting the question is.
  - How well the answer is structured

I would rather make a decision basing on such kind of analysis.

Comment: On the other hand, reputation on stack exchange sites is mostly built by exactly those points you mention later in your answer. I think the reputation system has already been well thought through (most likely by a team of people), so one can rely on it. It will most likely be less subjective than when you randomly read a selection of a few questions/answers.

Answer (score 1):

SQA or any other stack exchange sites won't directly get you a new position/job/project. However, it can be a contributing factor when someone in a company is deciding about whether to hire you or not. Therefore, if you've been active here, it seems a good idea to mention your profile in your CV, or to point out some of your better answers/questions.